# How does high entropy targets relate to less variance of the gradient between training cases?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, variance, entropy

I've been trying to understand the [Distilling the Knowledge in a Neural Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02531.pdf) paper by Hinton et al. But I cannot fully understand this:

> When the soft targets have high entropy, they provide much more information per training case than hard targets and much less variance in the gradient between training cases [...]

The information part is very clear, but how does high entropy correlate to less variance between training cases?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a trained network already, when you run an example through it, the gradient will not have a very high variance.

The gradient varies a lot when you are training a network from the scratch but then it stops varying much since it understands the pattern.